# ECONNREFUSED when using apollo client to do graphQL query from getInitialProps method in nextjs

Tags: nginx, graphql, apollo-client, next.js

Following the [with-apollo-auth](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-apollo-auth) example
Successful behavior when I do client-side ApolloConsumer query. I pass the client through and query works.

Unsuccessful behavior when I attempt to do a server side query through getInitialProps. I pass the client through a handler that calls the same query and I get a ECONN refused error as shown below.

[image]

**Steps to reproduce the behavior:**

I set up my ApolloClient in the init-apollo file as follows:

```
  const httpLink = createHttpLink({
    uri: 'http://localhost:8080/api/graphql',
    credentials: 'same-origin'
  })

  const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
    const token = getToken()
    return {
      headers: {
        ...headers,
        authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : ''
      }
    }
  })

  return new ApolloClient({
    connectToDevTools: process.browser,
    ssrMode: !process.browser, // Disables forceFetch on the server (so queries are only run once)
    link: ApolloLink.from([ authLink, httpLink ]),
    cache: new InMemoryCache().restore(initialState || {})
  })
```

I set up my query as follows:

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag'

export default apolloClient => {
  apolloClient
    .query({
      query: gql`
        {
          getUser {
            id
          }
        }
      `
    })
    .then(({data}) => {
      console.log(data);
      return { userDetails: data.getUser }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      // Fail gracefully
      console.log(err);
      return { userDetails: {} }
    })
  }
```

I set up my getInitialProps function in the index.js file within the pages directory:

```
  import getUser from '../shared/services/get-user';

  static async getInitialProps (context) {
    const results = await getUser(context.apolloClient)
    console.log(results);
    return {}
  }
```

**Expected behavior**
I expect to see a log of the user returned, however I get an ECONNREFUSED error as shown above.

System information
OS: macOS Mojave
Browser (if applies) Chrome
Version of Next.js: 7.0.2
Version of ApolloClient: 2.4.12l
Additional context
Using Absinthe (Elixir+Phoenix) GraphQL API, url specified: http://localhost:8080/api/graphq
Using docker-compose to spin up multiple containers. API and NextJS client are in separate containers sitting behind nginx server. Nginx server routes to relevant container depending on the url endpoint specified. **THIS COULD VERY WELL BE THE ISSUE BUT I CAN'T SEEM TO FIND A SOLUTION TO THIS.** If url contains api, client will be routed to my API container.

Here is the setup for my nginx configuration:

```
upstream client {
  server client:3000;
}

upstream api {
  server api:4000;
}

server {
  listen 80;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://client;
  }

  location /sockjs-node {
    proxy_pass http://client;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
  }

  location /api {
    rewrite /api/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://api;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although answered late, your should have given more info on your backend-api framework i.e. which framework are you running? I believe frontend is nextjs. All the same i thik your problem is with nginx configuration. Please `proxy_pass` your url via a port number and not a `\location` because they are two different web services. Try this configuration, notice the headers. Also configure your OS to listen port 8030.

```
server {
  listen 80;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://client;
    proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}

server {
  listen 8030;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://api;
    proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```